# json data caching for extjs grids

Tags: json, codeigniter, caching, extjs

I'm using [codeigniter (MVC)](http://www.codeigniter.com) and [extjs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) for an application.
The application contains many extjs grids with user related data. I want to cache the server json response up to particular time.

i got an idea to implement this as follows

```
if(cache file exists and not expired)
{
  $data = read_file(cache file path);// the cache file contains json encoded data with .json extention
}
else
 {
   $result = call to a model function; // returns data from a mysql query
   $data = json_encode( $result );
   //creating cache file with retrived data
   wite_file(cache file path, $data)
 }
echo $data; // $data is in json format
```

i want to implement caching this way. Is it the correct way?.
Totally i want to implement a custom json caching library for caching server json data for extjs grids

Is there any json caching libraries already available for codeigniter.
Please help with your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter has almost exactly what you describe built in. They refer to it as the Caching driver: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

In your case you would want to initiate it like this:

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'file', 'backup' => 'file'));

if ( ! $foo = $this->cache->get('foo'))
{
     echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
     $foo = 'foobarbaz!';

     // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
     $this->cache->save('foo', $foo, 300);
}

echo json_encode($foo);
```

It will write the cache data to file.

The down side in your case is that CI serializes the data in the cache file as opposed to using JSON. I suppose you could override the driver using json_encode() instead of serialize(). The method above would waste a little bit of resources in that it is both serializing AND using json encoding on output.

Comment: Thanks phirschybar. I look into codeigniter cache library, it uses serialize to write response data to cache file and unserialize to read data from cache file. I tried replacing serialize with json_encode, but its giving error  [json] (php_json_encode) type is unsupported, encoded as null. i think json_encode() can't encode mysql result object. I st-rucked here.Any suggestions please?

Comment: what version of php are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it sounds the good way to go, to know if the file is expired or not you can use the creation timestamp on the filesystem.

The [`stat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) function should give you enough information about the file to expire them whenever needed.

Codeigniter seems to have some [caching mechanism](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html) sadly it seems to be available only for webpages, if you are using views to render you JSON, you might be able to use that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply RageZ. i want to customize philsturgeon cache library instead of implementing my own.